# How Initial Foreign Key event in Function based View in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have two models, one is link to the other using foreign key. The Event model is view on the detail page. What I want is to initial the foreign key foreign element to the my Function based view that helps me process the form in Ajax and save. I want to initial the **event** field with the current Event being viewed

```
 Views.py

def create_attendance(request, slug):
    model = get_object_or_404(Event, slug=slug)
    context = {
                'event': model
            }
    response_data = {
                         'msg':'Your form has been submitted successfully' # response message
            }
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        fullname = request.POST.get('fullname')
        phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        company = request.POST.get('company')
        position = request.POST.get('position')
        event = model.objects.get(event=name)
        Attendance.objects.create(
            fullname = fullname,
            phone_number = phone_number,
            email = email,
            company = company,
            position = position,
            event = event
            
            )
        return JsonResponse(response_data) 
        print(event)
    return render(request, 'create_attendance.html', context)
```

```
Model.py

class Event(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True)


class Attendance(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: `get_object_or_404(Event, slug=slug)`returns an object **Event**. You have to remove  `e̶v̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶=̶ ̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶.̶o̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶s̶.̶g̶e̶t̶(̶e̶v̶e̶n̶t̶=̶n̶a̶m̶e̶)̶`. And use `event = model` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, you use the variable `event` in your code, but here's something that should work (not tested):

```
event = Event.objects.create(user=request.user)
attendance = Attendance.objects.create(
    fullname = fullname,
    phone_number = phone_number,
    email = email,
    company = company,
    position = position,
    event = event
)
```